# Wordpress Query, check a value against multiple keys

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress setup has a **Publication** custom post type and has 10 custom fields each corresponding to an author who may have contributed to that publication. Every post can have different authors in those fields or the same authors but in a different order. I am using Wordpress's `WP_Query` to search for posts matching my criteria. **I need to check a single author name against all the custom fields to see if it matches any one of them.** I tried doing this with the below code but it produces no result. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'publication',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'year_published',
            'value' => $selected_pub_year,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => array(
                'author_0_name',
                'author_1_name',
                'author_2_name',
                'author_3_name',
                'author_4_name',
                'author_5_name',
                'author_6_name',
                'author_7_name',
                'author_8_name',
                'author_9_name',
            ),
            'value' => $selected_pub_author,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

// The above meta-query may be modified through the use of this:
// echo "<pre>".print_r($args[meta_query][relation])."</pre>";

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added **OR relation** for post author query,Try to change your argument array as follow,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'publication',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'year_published',
            'value'   => $selected_pub_year,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
             array(
                'key'     => 'author_0_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_1_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_2_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_3_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_4_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_5_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_6_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_7_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_8_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_9_name',
                'value'   => $selected_pub_author,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks @Milap your code works wonderfully! However, isn't there any better way to do this than list all the different keys separately? This way a lot of the things are being repeated, so why doesn't it just work if we pass the key as an array of key names?

Comment: @ShahraizT. maybe there would be an option to make it in single array, you can work around it. if you find it, don't forget to post it here. anyway kindly accept an answer to make this thread complete.